# Há um método de fazer união de itens iguais em uma listar var em LINQ no C#?

Tags: c#, lista, linq, variáveis

Olá, bom dia, boa tarde ou boa noite, tudo bem?

Eu tenho um método que obtêm produtos de um banco de dados utilizando LINQ em C#, porem, nessa lista, existem produtos que são repetidos, então precisaria fazer uma união destes itens e ao invés de ter, por exemplo, 4, ter apenas 1, pois precisaria verificar se produto pode estar ativo ou não, há um método de fazer uma união desses itens repetidos?

Segue o Código da Consulta:

```
string TpDoc = "ORC";
string Ativo = "N";
var vendaPro = (from venPro in bdprincipalEntities.VendaProduto
                                join acab in bdprincipalEntities.Acabamento on venPro.CodAcabamento
                                 equals acab.CodAcabamento into vp_ac
                                from acab in vp_ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join pro in bdprincipalEntities.produtos on venPro.Pro_codnosso
                                equals pro.Pro_codnosso into vp_p
                                from pro in vp_p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join precPro in bdprincipalEntities.Preco_Produto on venPro.Pro_codnosso
                                 equals precPro.Pre_Codnosso into pp_p
                                from precPro in pp_p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where precPro.Pre_Acabamento == venPro.CodAcabamento
                                orderby venPro.VenPro_Seq, venPro.VenPro_SeqItem
                                select new
                                {
                                    Ven_CodigoPre = venPro.Ven_CodigoPre,
                                    Pro_codnosso = venPro.Pro_codnosso,
                                    Pro_descricao = pro.Pro_descricao,
                                    CodAcabamento = venPro.CodAcabamento,
                                    DescAcabamento = acab.DescAcabamento,
                                    Pre_Ativo = precPro.Pre_Ativo,
                                    Pro_ativo = pro.Pro_ativo,
                                }).Where(v => v.Ven_CodigoPre == Ven_codigoPre).Where(v => v.Pro_ativo == Ativo || v.Pre_Ativo == Ativo)
                                .ToList();
```

Como resultado final desse método, eu obtenho as seguintes informações:

```
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
}
```

Onde o resultado com a união ficaria algo como isso:

```
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
}
```

OBS.: A Lista com os resultados está em json, mas, é apenas para ilustrar o resultado final da consulta.

Eu já vi alguns métodos de união, mas, a maioria deles requerem que tenha 2 listas, nesse caso, é apenas uma lista com produto repetidos, alem disso, nesse exemplo, está sendo listado apenas 1 produto repetido varias vezes, então, o método que eu precisaria seria um que faça união não somente de um produto com varias repetições, um exemplo seria esse resultado abaixo:

```
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "ABA02",
    "Pro_descricao": "COMPONENTE ADICIONAL",
    "CodAcabamento": "BR/BR",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO/BRANCO",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "ABA02",
    "Pro_descricao": "COMPONENTE ADICIONAL",
    "CodAcabamento": "BR/BR",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO/BRANCO",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "ABA02",
    "Pro_descricao": "COMPONENTE ADICIONAL",
    "CodAcabamento": "BR/BR",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO/BRANCO",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
}
```

Onde o resultado final ficaria assim:

```
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "LD83/Q/MINIDIC",
    "Pro_descricao": "LD 83 ORIENT. 1MINIGZ10 (BD/FD)",
    "CodAcabamento": "BT/BT",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO TEXTURIZADO/BRANCO TEXTURIZ.",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
},
{
    "Ven_CodigoPre": 82664,
    "Pro_codnosso": "ABA02",
    "Pro_descricao": "COMPONENTE ADICIONAL",
    "CodAcabamento": "BR/BR",
    "DescAcabamento": "BRANCO/BRANCO",
    "Pre_Ativo": "N",
    "Pro_ativo": "S"
}
```

Desde já agradeço pela colaboração e auxilio de vocês.

Comment: Use [`group by`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar o método GroupBy antes da conversão da .ToList(), o código não retorna erros, porem, os registros não são agrupados, segue o modelo:`(...).Where(v => v.Pro_ativo == Ativo || v.Pre_Ativo == Ativo).GroupBy(p => p.Pro_codnosso).ToList()` . 
Possui algum outro método que eu possa utilizar ou alguma condição adicional que precise colocar no código atual?

Fico no aguardo

Comment: De uma lida nisso [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/group-elements-in-a-sequence) que com certeza vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método `Distinct();`, para items iguais em todas os atributos (isso pode não funcionar bem para objetos complexos, então você teria que usar a mesmo função, porém sobrescrevendo o comparador). 
Alternativamente, você poderia usar groupBy juntamente com select: `suaList.GroupBy(x => new {x.Propriedade1, x.Propriedade2}).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();` para comparar somente alguns atributos e retornar uma lista sem repetições.

Answer (score 1):

Antes do **.ToList();**, acrescente **.Distinct()**, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
List<int> semNumerosRepetidos = numeros.Distinct().ToList();
```